# How to find correspondent elements of two linearly transformed arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays of floats (x,y) with unique elements, one of them is a linear transform of the other `y=a*x+b`, for example:

```
a=0.95;
b1=3.33;
b2=5.55;
x=[1,3,4,6,9,13,20,22,31,35,37,40];
y=t1.collect.with_index{|z,i| i>6 ? z*a+b1 : z*a+b2}
=> [6.5, 8.4, 9.35, 11.25, 14.1, 17.9, 24.55, 24.23, 32.78, 36.58, 38.48, 41.33]
```

The linear transformation is applied with two different `b` values to the `x` array. Let's suppose I don't know the rule of the `b` values aplied, here the function of the index `i`.

My goal is that if I know the value of `a` and I also know the possible values of `b` in the form of a two element array `bs=[b1,b2]`, then I would like to find out the correspondent `b` value for every element of `y` even if the two arrays (x,y) are scrambled. My idea (doesn't work correctly, I need help here):

```
def ybs(x,y,bs,a)
  difference=0.0
  xelem=0.0
  return y.map do |z| 
    cb=bs.min_by do |b| 
      xelem=x.min_by do |q| 
        (q-(z-b)*1/a).abs
      end
      difference=(xelem-(z-b)*1/a).abs
    end
    difference=(xelem-(z-cb)*1/a).abs
    [z,xelem,(z-cb)*1/a,cb,difference]
   end
end
```

It would return 4 values for every elements of the `y` array in the form:

```
[<value from y>,<correspondent value from x>,<inverse transformed value of y, should be equal to xelem>,<correspondent b value of the linear transformation>,<difference, error, usually 0.0>]
```

My output when I call `ybs(x,y,bs,a)`:

```
[[1, 6.5, -2.4526315789473685, 3.33, 8.952631578947368],
 [3, 6.5, -0.34736842105263166, 3.33, 6.847368421052631],
 [4, 6.5, 0.7052631578947368, 3.33, 5.794736842105263],
 [6, 6.5, 2.8105263157894735, 3.33, 3.6894736842105265],
 [9, 6.5, 5.968421052631579, 3.33, 0.5315789473684207],
 [13, 8.4, 7.842105263157896, 5.55, 0.5578947368421048],
 [20, 14.1, 17.547368421052635, 3.33, 3.4473684210526354],
 [22, 17.9, 17.31578947368421, 5.55, 0.5842105263157897],
 [31, 24.55, 26.789473684210527, 5.55, 2.2394736842105267],
 [35, 32.78, 33.33684210526316, 3.33, 0.5568421052631578],
 [37, 32.78, 33.10526315789474, 5.55, 0.3252631578947387],
 [40, 36.58, 38.6, 3.33, 2.020000000000003]]
```

I need this method for my subtitle syncing program, where different parts of the subtitles' time codes can be shifted by different amount, for example when a scene is missing from a different version of the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you weren't keeping your ordered pairs together. For each y value, your code 'thinks' that the x associated with it is the one for which `(q-(z-b)*1/a).abs` is the least. However, it could be that taking the "wrong" b value for the y value being considered, together with the wrong x value would lead to a value of `(q-(z-b)*1/a).abs` that was slightly (or much) less than that which you get by taking the "right" `b` and `x` values.

I ran your code (rounding off the values for clarity) and got:

```
[6.5, 1.0, 1.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[8.4, 3.0, 3.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[9.35, 4.0, 4.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[11.25, 6.0, 6.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[14.1, 9.0, 9.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[17.9, 13.0, 13.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[24.55, 20.0, 20.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[24.23, 20.0, 22.0, 3.33, 2.0]
[32.78, 31.0, 31.0, 3.33, 0.0]
[36.58, 31.0, 35.0, 3.33, 4.0]
[38.48, 35.0, 37.0, 3.33, 2.0]
[41.33, 37.0, 40.0, 3.33, 3.0]
```

You can see that the x values do not follow the original sequence. Since there's no need to take a chance letting 'y's get associated with the wrong 'x's, lets just force them to stay together.

Here is how I modified your code to keep the `y`s and `x`s together.

```
def ybs(pairs,bs,a)
  difference=0.0
  xelem=0.0
  return pairs.map do |pair|
    x,y = pair[0], pair[1]
    cb = bs.min_by do |b|
      (x-(y-b)*1/a).abs
    end
    difference = (x-(y-cb)*1/a).abs
    [y,x,(y-cb)*1/a,cb,difference]
  end
end

a=0.95;
b1=3.33;
b2=5.55;
bs = [b1, b2]
x=[1,3,4,6,9,13,20,22,31,35,37,40];
y=x.collect.with_index{|z,i| i>6 ? z*a+b1 : z*a+b2}
c = x.count-1
pairs = (0..c).collect do |i|
  [x[i],y[i]]
end

r = ybs(pairs,bs,a)
r.each do |q|
  (0..4).each do |p|
    q[p] = q[p].round(2)
  end
  p q
end
```

and here is my output:

```
[6.5, 1.0, 1.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[8.4, 3.0, 3.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[9.35, 4.0, 4.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[11.25, 6.0, 6.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[14.1, 9.0, 9.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[17.9, 13.0, 13.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[24.55, 20.0, 20.0, 5.55, 0.0]
[24.23, 22.0, 22.0, 3.33, 0.0]
[32.78, 31.0, 31.0, 3.33, 0.0]
[36.58, 35.0, 35.0, 3.33, 0.0]
[38.48, 37.0, 37.0, 3.33, 0.0]
[41.33, 40.0, 40.0, 3.33, 0.0]
```

All of the errors are small, and the `b`s are correct... they are `5.55` until the 7th row, where they switch to 3.33, as your rule prescribes.